# Xamarin - Can I develop Android apps on Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I've spent more than a day trying to install and get this up and running and it just doesn't seem to be working.  I tried installing saying that I have Visual Studio.. and then when I run the app, I have no emulators.  I try to install Android Emulator for Visual Studio and it says I need Windows 8.

I then again try to install Xamarin but this time i click that i do NOT have Visual Studio.. then it seems like it's download Visual Studio 2015 for me.. but then at the end, it seems like the install didn't go correctly and I don't even see an executable for VS2015 and I just don't know what's going on here.

It says here

> The minimum operating system version is Windows 7. Xamarin.Forms Windows support requires Windows 8.1, and Xamarin.Forms UWP support requires Windows 10.

from https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/requirements/#windows

so what am I missing here?  I'm going nuts

Comment: The Visual Studio Android emulator is not associated with Xamarin. That product has different system requirements than Xamarin. [From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228280.aspx) you can see that Visual Studio's Android Emulator requires at least Windows 8. You can use Google's Android emulator if you need to keep using Windows 7.

Comment: @dylansturg I thought I needed Visual Studio Android emulator to emulate an Android device for Xamarin (my device list is empty).  So is this not true?  Do I not need Visual Studio Android emulator for me to develop and run apps with my setup?

Comment: You do not need to use Visual Studio's Android emulator. There are other emulators available: Google has emulators, Genymotion is nice, and I'm sure there are others. In fact, you can test on a real device and not even use an emulator. When building an Android app with Xamarin, it is a native Android app - you don't need a special device or emulator to run your app.

Answer (score 3):

The minimum operating system version is Windows 7. But you need Windows 7 Service Pack 1. It need for VS15 - [detail](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-system-requirements-vs.aspx#1)

You can not use on windows 7:

-Xamarin Forms

-Visual Studio emulator for android

-can't use shared code for windows store

I advise you to be updated to Windows 10.

Comment: thank you for the information.  i felt like it wasn't presented very clearly anywhere